# How to use $firebaseArray to syncronize to particular group of child?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Hi I am new to Angularfire.I have database structure as follow,

```
--+User
  |
  +---+record1
  |   |
  |   +item1
  |
  +---+record2
  |   |
  |   +item2
  |
  +---+record3
  |
  |
  +...
```

For a user I need to track many record say 3 records for a user. I need to change the $firebaseArray dynamically for every user.

This is what I have tried until now,

```
$scope.citem=$firebaseArray( firebase.database().ref('user/record1'));

$scope.citem.push($firebaseArray( firebase.database().ref('user/record2'))[0]);
```

Here I tried to get the path record1 and record2 but my result is pointing to item1 and item2. Am I wrong someway.Is there some other way?Can someone please help me

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you having exactly? Are you getting ay errors?